# Bottom navigation positioning

Tags: css, material-design, material-ui, progressive-web-apps

How do i make sure the [bottom navigation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/bottom-navigation) is always, well, at the bottom regardless of screen size?

```
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
```

This works but when keyboard is open on a phone, it will push the navigation bar up.

Answer (score 0):

try changin position to this :

```
position:fixed;
```

Comment: It's still the same